# jQuery: Selecting the inner html of an elemnt with a specific value and assign it to a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<dl class="item-options">
    <dt>dt1</dt>
    <dd>dd1</dd>
    <dt>dt2</dt>
    <dd>ss2</dd>
</dl>
```

Now I want to access the dt1 by its content and assign the value from dd1 to it. I am iterating over all the dds in a each loop, so for each dd I access, I want to get the content from the matching dt.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "get the content from the matching dt", how exactly are they linked together? Showing us the code you already have would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var it = $(".item-options dt").first().text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hyskp/

If dt1 isn't the first element, you could loop over each `dt`:

```
$("dt").each(function(e) {
   var dt = $(this).text();
   if (dt == "dt1") {
     // logic   
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xErBM/

Comment: What if the element with `dt1` isn't the first element, or - even more likely - you don't **know** which position it's in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to select the element(s) that contain specific text, like so:

```
$('.item-options dt:contains("dt1")')
```

That would select the `<dt>` element that has the string "dt1" as part of its text. Note that it's not an exact match, so it would also select elements that contain "dt1" as a substring.